# how can pass a variable from one action to another without redirect to another action in Zend framework(bsc)

Tags: zend-framework

```
public function helloAction() {
    $a =10;

}
public function thanksAction() {
    $b = 20;
    $b = $b + $a; //`enter code here` how can i get this $a variable value from helloAction() to thanksAction()
// without use _redirect() and i mean don't send url helloAction() to thanksAction() by any method
}
```

give the solution in zend framework. enter code here` how can i get this $a variable value from helloAction() to thanksAction() without use _redirect() and i mean don't send url helloAction() to thanksAction() by any method

Comment: Set $a value in session or registry in helloAction method and then use this in thanksAction

Comment: What do you mean by bsc?

Answer (score 4):

There are different options, all of which depends on what your exact requirement is :

Option 1:  Forward - From the question, it looks like you want to execute helloAction first, and then thanksAction() so that $a is set to 10 and then passed to thanksAction. For that, you can use _forward method. It will not change the url, but will pass the execution to the action specified.

```
       public function helloAction() {
               $a =10;
               $this->_forward("thanks","index", null, array('a' => $a));
        }
        public function thanksAction() {
               $a = $this->_getParam("a");
               $b = 20;
               $b = $b + $a; 
         }
 Note the _forward() will process all statements in helloAction(), skip its view script, and process all the statements in thanksAction and display its view script.`
```

Option 2: Set the variable $a as a class parameter,  access it with $this in your actions.

```
      public function helloAction() {
            $this->a =10;

      }
      public function thanksAction() {
            $b = 20;
            $b = $b + $this->a; 
      }
```

Option 3: Set the value in session or Zend registry and access wherever required.

All said and done, as @vascowhite pointed out in his answer, if you come across a situation where you need to pass parameters between actions not via GET,POST or SESSION, you might have some design issues there. One thing you can do is to move the statements to a regular function and call it from helloAction, like:

```
     public function helloAction() {
            $a =10;
            $c = $this->processA($a);

      }
      protected function processA($a) {
            $b = 20;
            $b = $b + $a; 
            return $b;
      }
```

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't have to. Controllers should never need to talk to each other. If there is functionality that will be common to more than one controller, then it should be moved into one of the model layers.

You should be striving for skinny controllers that have a minimum of logic in them. Your requirement for one controller to access another is a code smell that indicates you need to do some re-factoring. Take a hard, critical look at your design and think about how you can avoid this situation, it will only get more complex if you continue with it.

After 4 years of ZF development and 10 completed projects as a lone developer I am speaking from bitter experience, especially when it comes to maintaining the older projects. I now have an unbreakable rule that controllers never share anything.

Comment: I just forgot to add this point to mine. Did +1, it has to be a +500 :-)

Answer (score 0):

**janenz00** has covered almost everything, but I would like to add that you should not forget that each controller is a class and each action is a function and can be called as such.

```
      public function helloAction() {
            $a =10;
            $this->thanksAction($a);

      }
      public function thanksAction($a) {
            $b = 20;
            $b = $b + $a; 
      }
```

Please note that in the ZF world you are executing helloAction so the view that will be displayed after both actions have completed is the hello view. You can also use this to handle common logic/validation/code within a controller when there is no need for a actionHelper.